# Comparing 2nd largest item per group to the largest item in the group using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have a relational database for a Burger Building application that a restaurant uses. Two of the tables contained in the DB are `Category` and `Item`.  These are used to display the categories and then the customer can select a category (E.G. Buns) and view all of the children contained in that category and choose which ones to add to their order.  The two tables are linked using a field called `CategoryID`.

The Item database contains amongst many, the following fields: `ItemID`, `ItemName`, `TimesOrdered`, `CategoryID`.

One of the required functions is to view the item that has been ordered the most (most popular) per category.  This can be retrieved from the `TimesOrdered` field.  However, if two items have been ordered the same amount of times, then there is technically not any item in that category that has been ordered the most.

Therefore, the largest `TimesOrdered` field will have to be compared to the second largest `TimesOrdered` field to determine if any items have been ordered the most for that category.

Is there any way to achieve this using SQL?  For example, showing the `ItemID` for each category (using Grouping on CategoryID) that has been ordered the most as long as the item that has been ordered the second most has been ordered less times than the item that has been ordered the most.

I know that this can obviously be done by simply viewing the first two items and comparing the second record's `TimesOrdered` field with the first record's `TimesOrdered` field, but as a challenge and a way to improve my SQL, is their any way to get the desired results by using a single SQL statement?

Thanks in advance for any responses :)

[image: Item table sample data]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible to share some sample data? For example, what types of records are in your `Item` table?

How specifically is your `Item` table related to your `Category` table? Do you have multiple items per category?

I'd also want to know how the `TimesOrdered` field gets updated. Is this something that is updated manually by a user whenever that item is ordered, or handled by code?

Regarding  the output: It sounds like you want to display, by category, the item with the most orders. Is this correct? If so, would it be displayed via a query the user runs? It sounds like you want to display something different for categories with multiple items having the "max ItemCount" for that category. If a given category has multiple items with max ItemCount, what should display for that category? Could you provide some sample output of what you're expecting to see?

I'm thinking the best way to handle this would be to use multiple sub-queries, which can get rather hairy in Access. It might be best to break this into separate queries in Access, which you can progressively select from

1. Create a query Q1 that shows the max `TimesOrdered` for each category.
2. Create a query `Q2` that uses `Q1` to figure out how many items for each category have the max `TimesOrdered` value.
3. Depending on how you want to display the final results, you could create a new query, `Q3`, that either shows NULL for the item in that category (if there's a tie), or the appropriate item. Basically, you'd display the item from each category where the `TimesOrdered` matches the max `TimesOrdered` for that category (having to possibly do special handling for categories with ties).

Another thing you might want to think about: What about having a separate Orders table that stores details of each order, rather than having a TimesOrdered field? Of course, that would complicate your queries further, but give you more data to report on.

Comment: Refer to the newly attached images for the relationships :)  `TimesOrdered` gets updated through code every time that a customer places their order.  The programs runs through all of the items in the order and increases the amount of times that it has been ordered by 1.

Comment: So, based on the current data, you'd show **Plain Buns** as the item with the max `TimesOrdered` value in the **Buns** category, and **Bean Patty** as the item with the max ``TimesOrdered`` value in the **Patty** category, right?

What about if plain buns were removed, and you had **Banting Buns** and **Rye Buns** tied for 5 each? What would you expect to see for the max item in the Buns category?

Comment: I would like to see the `ItemID` for each item that has been ordered the most per category: E.G. 1 for the `CategoryID`, and then 5 for the `ItemID` (Since **Plain buns** would have been ordered the most) - a simple 2 collumn query.  However, in the case of the **Banting Buns** and **Rye Buns**, the query should either show a zero as the `CategoryID` for the item that has been ordered the most or simply not show the **Buns** group in the query at all.

Comment: I think my idea of using separate queries that build on each other might still be the best. Q1 (CategoryID, CategoryName, MaxTimesOrdered); Q2 (CategoryID, CategoryName, MaxTimesOrdered, ItemsWithMaxTimesOrdered); Q3 (CategoryID, CategoryName, ItemWithMaxTimesOrdered)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  That actually makes a lot of sense and it seems so simple now.  Also, thanks for the `Order` table tip :)